# Groovy code to add a choice parameter dynamically

Tags: jenkins-groovy

Is there a way through groovy code that I can add a parameter dynamically to a choice parameter.
The reason I need it is, I  want to build a job which in turn will check for a particular Jenkins job where the parameter needs to be added.

How can I remove the manual effort of doing this?

Example --
Job1 should be pipeline job.It has three parameters - 1.) newValue 2.)jobName 3.)ParameterName(This parameter has to be the name of choice parameter of another job mentioned in "jobName" whose new value should be added which is defined in "newValue" parameter.)

Depending upon the value of parameters "newValue" and "jobName" and "ParameterName". 
This job should make an updation to another Job whose name is defined in "jobName" and add the choice parameter value "newValue" to the "ParameterName" of given "jobName".

Comment: As far as I understand, do you want to pass a value to a pipeline depending on the result of a previous job build? If yes, you can use the Jenkins API to get the builds

Comment: Actually what i need is ,for example---->
I have a job1. I need to write a groovy code in it, which in turn could  help me to update/delete a choice parameter value in any other  jenkins job(Say Job2,which already has a choice parameter values in it) (depending upon in which job i want to update/delete a paramerter value).

Comment: And yes i  need to write a pipeline.

Comment: I think you should update your question with a more clear example. I don't really understand the problem, sorry

Comment: Let me know if you understand this example.